# how to use instance attribute to define a class attribute?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes

I'm trying to use the name in my **init** for my class attribute, `attr` but it seems that's impossible.
here's the code:

```
class B:

    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return owner.valEditNew(self.val)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        return


class A:

    def __init__(self, name = 'def_name'):
        self.name = name

    attr = B('G120')

    def valEditNew(val):
        val += ' @edited'
        return val

a = A('JJ')
print(a.attr)
```

that's it if i use self.name or name or ... in place of `G120`>>>
`builtins.NameError: name 'self' is not defined`
if that's not possible, can you show me the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access attribute of the instance that contains the descriptor object, use `instance` parameter of `__get__` / `__set__`:

```
class B:

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance.valEditNew(instance.name)  # <---

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        return


class A:

    attr = B()

    def __init__(self, name='def_name'):
        self.name = name

    def valEditNew(self, val):
        val += ' @edited'
        return val


a = A('JJ')
print(a.attr)
# prints => JJ @edited
```

Comment: I know that I'm overriding __get__ and __set__ methods here... where can I find the original ones ?

Comment: @shiyonsufa, I recommend you to read https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html or https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors

Comment: @shiyonsufa, B is not subclass of any class, but `object` which does not have `__get__`, `__set__`; no overriding is done.  Try `object.__get__` in interactive shell.